# Estimate to prove regularity of bounded Navier-Stokes solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading the proof of the regularity condition for Navier-Stokes, $L^\infty\Rightarrow C^\infty$. I'm confused by the estimate
\begin{align*}
\|\int_0^t\mathbb P\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)ds\|_{B_{\infty,\infty}^{(k+1)/2}}\leq C\|u\|_{L^\infty((T_0,T_2),B_{\infty,\infty}^{k/2})}^2\int_{T_0}^t\max\{(t-s)^{-3/4},1\}ds
\end{align*}
with $\mathbb P$ the Leray projection, $B_{p,q}^s$ a Besov space, $u\in L^\infty((T_0,T_2),B_{\infty,\infty}^{k/2})^d$.

I know that $B_{\infty,\infty}^{k/2}$ is an algebra with pointwise multiplication so $u\otimes u(t)\in(B_{\infty,\infty}^{k/2})^{d\times d}$, but I feel like taking $\mathbb P\nabla\cdot u$ should make it lose a whole derivative, not $1/2$. I also don't see where the $\max\{(t-s)^{-3/4},1\}$ comes from.

Comment: Referring to my copy of Lemarie-Rieusset's book, I suspect that it is a typo.  After all, in the same proof he says $\mathbb{P}\nabla\cdot$ maps $B^k$ to $B^{k-1}$.  I feel like there should be a $e^{(t-s)\Delta}$ in the integral on the left side.  This would give you some regularity back and might be the source of the $(t-s)^{-3/4}$ term (see theorem 5.3).

Comment: @mathematician Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @mathematician I'll delete the question unless you want to make that an answer and I'll accept it.